# Convert Bytes to Percentage

Tags: objective-c, byte

I want to convert bytes to a percentage. The percentage will represent the total amount a file that has been uploaded.

For example, I have:

```
int64_t totalBytesSent
int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend
```

I want to convert that into a percentage (float).

I've tried this:

```
int64_t percentage = totalBytesSent/totalBytesExpectedToSend;
```

and this:

```
[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:totalBytesSent];
[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:totalBytesExpectedToSend];
CGFloat = [totalBytesSent longLongValue]/[totalBytesExpectedToSend longLongValue];
```

I think I am missing something in trying to do 'byte-math'. Does anyone know how to convert bytes to a percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with:

```
int64_t percentage = totalBytesSent/totalBytesExpectedToSend;
```

This would return a number between 0 and 1...but you're doing math with integers.  Cast one of them to a `CGFloat`, `float`, `double`, etc, then multiply it by 100, or multiply `totalBytesSent` by 100 before dividing if you don't want to do floating-point math:

```
int64_t percentage = (double)totalBytesSent/totalBytesExpectedToSend * 100;    //uses floating point math, slower
//or
int64_t percentage = totalBytesSent*100/totalBytesExpectedToSend;  //integer division, faster
```

Also, why are you using `int64` for absolutely everything?  Do you really need to send exabytes of data?  `unsigned` would probably be the best choice:

```
unsigned totalBytesSent
unsigned totalBytesExpectedToSend

unsigned percentage = totalBytesSent*100/totalBytesExpectedToSend;
```

If you want a decimal point in your percentage, use floating-point math to divide and store the result in a floating-point type:

```
CGFloat percentage = totalBytesSent*100/totalBytesExpectedToSend;
```

Comment: Great! That worked! Thanks! I am not using int64_t, its a parameter coming from a third-party library in a block.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you divide one integer value (doesn't matter which size of integer) by a bigger integer value the result will always be 0.

Either multiply the totalBytesSent value with 100 before dividing if you don't need decimals or convert values to a floating point value before doing the division.

The following code will result in the percentage as a value between 0 and 100:

```
int64_t percentage = totalBytesSent*100/totalBytesExpectedToSend;
```